# How to change my Query to a single command in MySql?

Tags: mysql, sql

My order has two fields called buyerid and sellerid.
I want to get both id according to the same condition, I can use two search statements to union them, but I have to search them two times. How to search them one time in one Select statement? Now my statement is:

```
select sellerid from order where status=2 and createtime>'2015-05-25 8:00:00'
 union all
select buyerid from order where status=2 and createtime>'2015-05-25 8:00:00'
```

How to change them to one statement?

```
-- This is what I try to change to equal to above,but it is wrong.
select (buyerid+sellerid) from order where status=2 and createtime>'2015-05-25 8:00:00'
```

Comment: you can use JOIN statement

Comment: Can you give me a example?

Comment: I updated my answer can you check it once..

Comment: @flower, oh nvm. I thought they are 2 different tables.

Comment: doesnt your 2nd sql already get you want you want to achieve?

Comment: if you still awaiting for desired output then provide some sample data and your desired result set.

Comment: @Mox,No, I have not get my achievement.

Comment: You’re out of luck when it comes to mysql, what you have is basically the best that can be done. In recent versions of PostgreSQL, Oracle and DB2 you can use the SQL99 construction LATERAL: `select x.id from order cross join LATERAL ( values (order.sellerid), (order.byerid) ) x (id)`. SQL Server provides CROSS APPLY that can achive the same thing. The syntax in my example works for DB2 but might have to be slightly adjusted for the other DBMS:s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you're looking for, if I understood you right:

```
SELECT q.id FROM

(select sellerid as id, status, createtime from order
 union all
select buyerid as id, status, createtime from order) AS q

WHERE status=2 and createtime>'2015-05-25 8:00:00'
```

I'd still go for your first attempt, not sure wether my solution is more efficient.

Comment: I don't think MySQL:s optimizer will understand how to push the outer predicates into the legs of the union. In case status and createtime are properly index your query will therefor most likely cause more rows to be read than the OP's query.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want this:

```
select sellerid, buyerid from order
where status=2 and createtime>'2015-05-25 8:00:00'
```

This will return the two columns you want.

Or am I missing something about how you want the results returned?

If you can concat, use:

```
select CONCAT(sellerid, ' ', buyerid) from order
where status=2 and createtime>'2015-05-25 8:00:00'
```

Comment: I just want to return one column

Comment: @flower is it viable to concat the columns?

Comment: @flower I am not wrong. You did not specify what you wanted, I am simply guessing. If you want another delimiter that is not the space char, replace it in the `concat()`

Comment: ,What I want is not two column or  one column with blank using concat.What I want is one column but the result is two rows.

Comment: @flower If you want two separate rows for each row in the table, one for the sellerID and one for the buyerID, you have to do two queries.

Comment: *"I just want to return one column"* uh, @flower, that really does not make any sense.  You want one column, two rows?  What possible rationale makes that more sensible than getting one row, two columns?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot,I want to loop the result,so that the result return one column will be better.

Comment: @flower if you want to loop, save both colums in an array and loop through the array, and you're done. What you are trying to do is simply a mess and does not make much sense...

Comment: @BlunT,Thank you.I   haven't touched mysql loop through the array.I will try.

Answer (score 0):

I think these sql will useful to you.

```
     select o1.sellerid+o2.buyerid as sum_value 
    from order as o1 join order as o2 on o1.status = o2.status 
and o1.status =2 and createtime > '2015-05-25 8:00:00'
```

Thank you.

Comment: I just want to reurn one result.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select buyerid || sellerid from order where status=2 and createtime>'2015-05-25 8:00:00'
```